# Validation Email with .Net core IDENTITY always returns Invalid token

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity, email-validation

I have a problem with my validation email method. I only user default Identity configuration.

I send an email like this :

```
    [HttpPost("register")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterAsync(UserRegisterViewModel model)
    {
        //// creattion of user

        var createdUser = await _userRepository.GetUserByEmailAsync(user.Email);

        string titleMail = "My title";
        string textMail = "My Body";
        string url = await GenerateEmailConfirmationUrl(createdUser);

        await _emailHelper.SendMailAsync(new Helpers.Models.SendMailModel()
        {
            To = new List<string>() { model.Email },
            Title = titleMail,
            Body = $"{textMail} <a href='{url}'>ICI</a>",
        });

        /// etc ...
    }

private async Task<string> GenerateEmailConfirmationUrl(UserDto user)
    {
        var token = await _authRepository.GetEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);

        string url = $"{_configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:ApplicationUrl").Value}/auth/email-validation?email={user.Email}&token={Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(token)}";

        return url;
    }
```

**RepositoryFile**

```
 public async Task<string> GetEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(User user)
        {
            return await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
        }
```

And this how I do the validation :

```
  [HttpGet]
        [Route("email-validation")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> EmailValidation(string email, string token)
        {
            var user = await _authRepository.GetUserByEmail(email);

            if (user == null) return Unauthorized();

            var decryptedToken = Base64UrlEncoder.Decode(token);

            var result = await _authRepository.EmailValidationAsync(user, decryptedToken);

            if (result.Succeeded)
                return Ok();

            return BadRequest(result.Errors);
        }
```

When I check what I send and what I get I see that the token are exactly the same but
await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(_mapper.Map(user), token);
always return InvalidToken error and I really don't understand why.